# Apple UK website CSS, *padding-top:0; What does this mean?

Tags: css, xhtml

```
#content { padding-top: 13px; *padding-top: 0; }
```

[View Source](http://www.apple.com/uk/)

My Question is, what does the * do in this example?

It's from the source code on apple.com/uk website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My Question is, what does the * do in
>   this example?

It is a CSS hack used to target IE6 and IE7.

```
#content {
    padding-top: 13px; /* for standard-compliant browsers */
    *padding-top: 0; /* for IE6 and IE7 */
}
```

**Note:** It is bad idea to go for CSS hacks. The better approach to target IE is to use [IE conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Comment: SO rather than using *html id{padding-top:0;} or *paddding etc  use <!--[if IE 6]>
 the css
<![endif]-->

Answer (score 1):

It's a hack to serve IE, which improperly parses it, padding-top of 0.